# Adding core data to existing tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have found the way I need to implement a sections collapsable/expandible tableView, but it is populating the row object from the code itself. I have just created a core data entity and want know to populate the row objects with it. I need help converting this particular code to let me add core data objects.
This is my current code:

```
    //

#import "CollapsableTableViewViewController.h"
#import "CollapsableTableView.h"
#import "CollapsableTableViewAppDelegate.h"


@interface CollapsableTableViewViewController()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@end


@implementation CollapsableTableViewViewController
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;

/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //1
    CollapsableTableViewAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    //2
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;


      self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }







    CollapsableTableView* tableView = (CollapsableTableView*) myTableView;
    tableView.collapsableTableViewDelegate = self;

//    [tableView setIsCollapsed:YES forHeaderWithTitle:@"First Section"];
//    [tableView setIsCollapsed:YES forHeaderWithTitle:@"Second Section"];
//    [tableView setIsCollapsed:YES forHeaderWithTitle:@"Third Section"];
//    [tableView setIsCollapsed:YES forHeaderWithTitle:@"Fourth Section"];
//    [tableView setIsCollapsed:YES forHeaderWithTitle:@"Fifth Section"];
}


// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [spinner release];
    spinner = nil;
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [spinner release];
    [super dealloc];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 10;
}


+ (NSString*) titleForHeaderForSection:(int) section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0 : return @"First Section";
        case 1 : return @"Second Section";
        case 2 : return @"Third Section";
        case 3 : return @"Fourth Section";
        case 4 : return @"Fifth Section";
        default : return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section no. %i",section + 1];
    }
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [CollapsableTableViewViewController titleForHeaderForSection:section];
}

// Uncomment the following two methods to use custom header views.
//- (UILabel *) createHeaderLabel: (UITableView *) tableView :(NSString *)headerTitle {
//    UILabel *titleLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
//    titleLabel.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width - 20, 60);
//    titleLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
//    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//    titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20];
//    titleLabel.text = headerTitle;
//    titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
//    return titleLabel;
//}
//
//- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
//{
//    // create the parent view that will hold header Label
//    UIView * customView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, tableView.frame.size.width , 60)]autorelease];
//    UILabel *titleLabel;
//    titleLabel = [self createHeaderLabel: tableView :[CollapsableTableViewViewController titleForHeaderForSection:section]];
//    
//    [customView addSubview:titleLabel];
//    
//    UILabel* collapsedLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,50,60)] autorelease];
//    collapsedLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
//    collapsedLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//    collapsedLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//    collapsedLabel.text = @"-";
//    collapsedLabel.tag = COLLAPSED_INDICATOR_LABEL_TAG;
//    [customView addSubview:collapsedLabel];
//    
//    customView.tag = section;
//    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//    return customView;
//}

//- (NSString*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
//{
//    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Footer %i",section + 1];
//}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case 2 : return 0;
        case 3 : return 30;
        default : return 8;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0 : cell.textLabel.text = @"First Cell"; break;
        case 1 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Second Cell"; break;
        case 2 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Third Cell"; break;
        case 3 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Fourth Cell"; break;
        case 4 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Fifth Cell"; break;
        case 5 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Sixth Cell"; break;
        case 6 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Seventh Cell"; break;
        case 7 : cell.textLabel.text = @"Eighth Cell"; break;
        default : cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.row + 1];
    }

    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = ...;

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark CollapsableTableViewDelegate

- (void) collapsableTableView:(CollapsableTableView*) tableView willCollapseSection:(NSInteger) section title:(NSString*) sectionTitle headerView:(UIView*) headerView
{
    [spinner startAnimating];
}

- (void) collapsableTableView:(CollapsableTableView*) tableView didCollapseSection:(NSInteger) section title:(NSString*) sectionTitle headerView:(UIView*) headerView
{
    [spinner stopAnimating];
}

- (void) collapsableTableView:(CollapsableTableView*) tableView willExpandSection:(NSInteger) section title:(NSString*) sectionTitle headerView:(UIView*) headerView
{
    [spinner startAnimating];
}

- (void) collapsableTableView:(CollapsableTableView*) tableView didExpandSection:(NSInteger) section title:(NSString*) sectionTitle headerView:(UIView*) headerView
{
    [spinner stopAnimating];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark IBAction methods

- (IBAction) toggleSection2
{
    NSString* sectionTitle = //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tag %i",1]; // Use this expression when using custom header views.
        [CollapsableTableViewViewController titleForHeaderForSection:1]; // Use this expression when specifying text for headers.
    CollapsableTableView* collapsableTableView = (CollapsableTableView*) myTableView;
    BOOL isCollapsed = [[collapsableTableView.headerTitleToIsCollapsedMap objectForKey:sectionTitle] boolValue];
    [collapsableTableView setIsCollapsed:! isCollapsed forHeaderWithTitle:sectionTitle];
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"ToDoItems" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"tdText" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}



@end
```

---

To add core data to my app I have done following:

```
1. Added CoreDataFramework to the project.
2. Added   #import <CoreData/CoreData.h> to the prefix.pch file
3. Added 
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator ;
to my AppDelegate.h file
4. Added 
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;

@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

to my AppDelegate.m file.

```
5. Added 
//core data
// 1
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}

//2
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    _managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

    return _managedObjectModel;
}

//3
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]
                                               stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Model.sqlite"]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                                   initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if(![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                  configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*Error for store creation should be handled in here*/
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

to  my AppDelegate.m file

```
6. Updated VC as new edited above in the question.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a very generic question and it is not possible to give a complete answer since needed a lot of effort.

Comment: First you could just start reading  [Core Data Tutorial for iOS: How To Use NSFetchedResultsController](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller).

Comment: I have just included the CoreData Framework and all core data stack to the AppDelegate.

Comment: what are you storing in your core data, what is your entity structure, Please explain them,we need clarification on them.

Comment: I will edit my question to add all information needed.

Comment: @flexaddicted, I have updated my question to include core data NSFetchedResultsCOntroller, as you proposed.

Comment: @santhu, I have updated my question to include core data NSFetchedResultsCOntroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best start for CoreData with UITableView is actually a new "from scratch" project based on the Xcode template "**Master Detail App with Core Data enabled**". In this template you see all the boiler plate code that is necessarry to fill a UITableView with CoreData entities.

[image]

[image]

Believe me: there is so much infrastructure to do - you cant "guess" this code or derive from the API description, or read from somewhere else. But if you open your existing project and this fresh template project. Then slowly scroll through the code of the MasterViewController and copy & paste all you need. This will give you a very fast start.

At least it worked for me in the same situation.

Comment: Thanks, but I have just opened another question about the issue. I have already included all core data stuff there.

Comment: OK. No prlbem. Anyway: My tip: in parallel to your existing project instatiate the Apple template MasterDetail with CoreData. One can learn a lot from there! Then take, what you need via copy & paste to your project.